# Go module replacement directive to replace sciter-sdk with shumatech

Tags: go, replace, module, sciter

I've learned golang a month ago and never have used golang modules, but today I needed it.

Initial problem:
I want to use sciter-sdk for GUI application. So, I decided to use [sciter-sdk](https://github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter). But it is a [bug](https://github.com/shumatech/go-sciter/tree/go1.15-fix) in getting library on go v1.15

My solution:
I've read about go modules' replace directive and have written [that](https://pastebin.com/jfXSbjL6) go.mod for my project

Common problem:
I thought that now everything will be ok, but it isn't.
When i run `go build -o ./bin/client ./src/client` it throws me that error:

```
go: found github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter in github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
go: found github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter/window in github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
go: github.com/shumatech/go-sciter@v0.5.1-0.20200928005155-90bed320196c used for two different module paths (github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter and github.com/shumatech/go-sciter)
```

I've found that error in golang [issues](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26904), but i can't figure out what to do here

Comment: Never used this module, but do you want to import `github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter` or `github.com/shumatech/go-sciter`? It seems to me it should be former.

Comment: I want to import `github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter`. I have already tried to import fork, but inside fork, it has imports from origin, so it tries to download origin and fails

Comment: You want to import `sciter-sdk` version but you replaced it with `shumatech` version?

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to replace `sciter-sdk` with `shumatech` and use `sciter-sdk` imports in code

Comment: Are you messing with me? :D

Comment: Oh, okay, i will explain.

Comment: I want that my code think that `shumatech` library it is original `sciter-sdk`. I want import `sciter-sdk` in code, but truly it will import `shumatech`